# SVN repository on mounted drive from Ubuntu

Tags: svn, ubuntu, cifs

I have been using SVN with a repository on a NAS drive, for my personal development.
Since it's single user, I'm not worried about file:// races.
As long as I used Windows machines, everything was fine.
Now I'm trying to develop on Ubuntu, and have managed to mount the NAS and check out the code.
On commit, however, I get an error:

```
svn: E000013: Can't set permissions on '/media/netdrive/svn/db/svn-U3CIu0': Permission denied
```

I am mounting using cifs (from fstab) and tried to commit as regular user and sudo with the same results.
The NAS drive is a WD World Edition on my lan

Any ideas?

Comment: Ever solved that one? I'm running into the same issue and can't find anything on the net. I have a disk I usually use with Windows which I automatically mount into my Ubuntu system. Access usually works without a problem, but SVN commands fail with the very same error you describe.

Comment: No solution in sight.  I eventually just gave up and moved on.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I'll have to try something totally different as well in that case.